# Хеширование строки java

Tags: java, mysql, строки, хеширование

Привет) Такая идея: пользователь вводит какой-то рассказ (допустим, в 300 символов) и его нужно сохранить в бд (в моем случае - mysql). Если говорить про mysql - варчар позволяет хранить всего 255 символов. Как можно захешировать строку так, чтобы она, например, всегда была длиной в каких-нибудь 12-16 символов, и большие "рассказы" можно было сохранять в бд, а потом, в случае чего - доставать и расшифровывать?

Answer (score 0):

Увы, сделать этого невозможно.

Для того, чтобы хранить рассказы в БД нужно всего-навсего использовать другой тип данных, а не VARCHAR длиной в 255 символов.

Например LARGETEXT (https://metanit.com/sql/mysql/2.3.php)

Comment: spring jpa так делает (мне нельзя ничего менять и необходимо чтобы бд и таблицы создавались на любых девайсах). С моей стороны только сжать текст. Либо указать в application.properties чтобы он конкретно для одной string использовал длинную строку, либо в аннотации  к Column либо Entity

Comment: Если строго текстовые строки, а не CLOB, то бить на несколько (меньше 256 символов) строк, используя аналог упорядоченного списка (с адекватным отображением в БД, конечно). Сжать строки при помощи того же GZIP можно, но тогда должно быть выигрышное отображение из бинарных данных в бинарные, иначе можно и проиграть в размере. Надо на реальных данных тестировать (а вдруг  они еще и многоязычные будут).

Comment: ..из бинарных в текстовые... конечно

Comment: @Anastasiya, в Spring можно изменить значение столбца по умолчанию через аннотации. И указать ему работать не с VARCHAR, а именно с текстовым типом.

Comment: @Egettl Спасибо! То что нужно! 
Column(lenght = 1000 / columnDefinition = "text/largetext") сработало)

Comment: @Anastasiya, а есть необходимость ставить тип поля в largetext с длиной всего в 1000 символов? Есть ощущение, что этот подход противоречит сам себе. largetext, как я посмотрел, позволяет хранить до 4 гб в поле. А вы ограничиваете его 1000-ей символов. Может стоит воспользоваться типом TEXT, который ближе к необходимой вам длине?

Comment: @Egettl это был пример) какие возможности я обнаружила у spring jpa - акцент вовсе не на числа